# Cache multiple images with limited pool size

Tags: javascript

I have a list of about 1000 urls for images that i want to cache.
I need to somehow limit the number of requests being performed in parallel.
What i do now is caching these images like this:

```
myImages.forEach(function(url) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
});
```

However this will cause many of the requests being pending.

What can i do to limit these request to let's say 10 being performed in parallel? Of course i don't want it to concern requests from different places in my application.

Comment: Have a look - [promise-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-limit)

Comment: and is there anything specific for AngularJS?